# Desktop : cannot see wallpaper, cannot right-click, cannot see icons

Tags: unity, desktop-environments

I have upgraded to 16.10 lately.

This morning after I logged in I saw that my wallpaper disappeared, that I could not right-click nor select the icons.

I'd prefer not to have to re-install Ubuntu. Does anyone know how to solve this problem? I might have to force re-install Unity or something else, but I need guidance?

Regards

Alexis.

[my current desktopp (see, wallpaper is not available)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blnA7.png)

Comment: Usually rebooting a couple of times fixes the odd time that happens. If it happens all the time changes are needed.